# Validar classe que executa uma query sql

Tags: php

Olá, possuo o seguinte código na minha dao.php.

```
public function insert(){
    $this->conn->beginTransaction();
    try {
        $sql = "QUERY DO INSERT AQUI .......";
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL));
        $stmt->execute();
        $this->conn->commit();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $this->conn->rollback();
    }
}
```

No meu controller:

```
public function insert(){
    $dao = new DAO($this->conn);
    return $dao->insert();
}
```

Aqui eu chamo a classe insert na minha view para executar o insert.

```
$class = new Controller($conn);
//Insert
$class->insert();
```

Agora a pergunta, como que eu faço para validar está chamada ? Se ela for executada mostra uma mensagem se não for mostra outra. Faço isso na minha view ou na dao ? E como ? Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

na sua `DAO` você pode adicionar um retorno do método sendo ele `true` ou `false`:

```
public function insert(){
    $this->conn->beginTransaction();
    try {
        $sql = "QUERY DO INSERT AQUI .......";
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL));
        $response = $stmt->execute();
        $this->conn->commit();
        return $response;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $this->conn->rollback();
        return false;
    }
}
```

e na sua `View` você pode tratar esse retorno se for `true` ou `false`, por exemplo:

```
$class = new Controller($conn);
//Insert
if($class->insert()){
    echo 'sucesso';
}else{
    echo 'erro';
}
```